# После каждого деплоя на Glassfish очищается база данных

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

В эклипсе создаю мавен проект из архетипа spring-mvc-quickstart. В файлах pom.xml, persistence.properties меняю с hsqldb на mysql, в файле
`UserServise.java` закоменнтирован кусок кода

```
    //@PostConstruct    
    //protected void initialize() {
        //accountRepository.save(new Account("user", "demo", "ROLE_USER"));
        //accountRepository.save(new Account("admin", "admin", "ROLE_ADMIN"));
    //}
```

Коннект с базой данных нормально проходит, таблица account создана скриптом, у базы данных свойство Engine равно InnoDb. После каждого деплоя на глассфиш ранее созданные записи в таблице удаляются. Подскажите, в каком направлении копать?

Comment: Покажи конфиг хибернейта. Или бин в спринге, который конфигурирует хибернейт

Comment: есть у хибернейта property - `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, проверь его значение. У тебя хибернейт ведёт так, как будто значение выставлено в `create`

Comment: Ответ нашелся в persistence.properties должно быть hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update